# Maximum area rectangle

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Given set of points `(x[1]; y[1]), (x[2]; y[2]), ..., (x[n]; y[n])` . We need to find maximum area of rectangle that we can get. Rectangle's vertexes should be in points set. Also, rectangle is not necessary be axis-aligned. For example, answer for `(1; 1), (2; 2), (2; 0); (3; 1)` is 2.
`n <= 1300; -10^9 <= x[i], y[i] <= 10^9`.
Can someone help me with this problem? My solution is brute-force O(N^3), it's giving TLE. I select some three points and find fourth.

Comment: task is from desing company interview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every pair of points determines a line L, which has a slope m and an intercept c. (Ignore vertical lines for now.) Instead of considering the intercept, let's work with a different quantity that gives much the same information: The distance d(L) between the line and the origin, i.e., the length of a line segment R perpendicular to L and connecting L to the origin. Additionally, we can talk about the "displacement" of a point along L: We can say that the point p on L where it meets R has displacement 0, and the point on L that is x "above" p (has distance x from p and higher y coordinate) has displacement x, with negative displacements for points "below" p. In fact, we don't need the intercept or d(L) to define the displacement of a point with respect to a line L -- just the line's slope. Define disp(m, q) to be the displacement of point q on a line with slope m.

Suppose a, b, c, d are the vertices of a rectangle, with sides ab, bc, cd and da. Observe that the line containing ab has the same slope m as the line containing cd, and (disp(m, a), disp(m, b)) = (disp(m, d), disp(m, c)). So the only 4-tuples of vertices that we need to test are those comprised of pairs of vertex pairs like ab and cd -- vertex pairs having the same slope and displacement pairs. Furthermore, one side length (shared by ab and cd) is equal to |disp(m, b) - disp(m, a)|, and the other side length will be |d(Lab) - d(Lcd)|, where Lab and Lcd are the lines containing the line segments ab and cd, respectively.

To find these 4-tuples of vertices efficiently:

- For all pairs of vertices i, j:

  - Let L be the line passing through i and j. Compute its slope m and distance d(L) from the origin. Also compute disp(m, i) and disp(m, j). If disp(m, i) <= disp(m, j), add the tuple (m, disp(m, i), disp(m, j), d(L)) to an array Z.
- Sort Z lexicographically. This will place all point pairs lying on lines of the same slope and having equal displacements in a contiguous block, ordered by increasing d(L).
- Scan through the array, looking for block boundaries -- positions k at which any of the first three tuple elements changes. Let prev be the last such k found (initially, prev = 0). For each such k:

  - Compute (Z[k-1][3] - Z[prev][3]) * (Z[k-1][2] - Z[k-1][1]). This is the area of the largest rectangle having a pair of sides with slope Z[k-1][0] and length (Z[k-1][2] - Z[k-1][1]). If this is greater than the maximum rectangle size found so far, update it.

This algorithm takes O(n^2 log n) time and O(n^2) space.

Comment: I wrote solution but it gives wrong answer to test (1; 1), (2; 2), (2; 0); (3; 1) :o
maybe my code is not correct, could you please check it?

Comment: What does it report as the solution for that input? Also are you using integer arithmetic? It is safest to use integers, even for things like slopes (store integer ratios a:b) since floating point arithmetic is unreliable when equality comparisons need to be made, as they do here.

Comment: ooh, ok, i will try to change to integer ratio;
it prints 0 to test

Comment: Remember to normalise, so that, e.g., 12:9 becomes 4:3.

Comment: Hmm, I just realised it's not practical to use integers for displacements, since they can be irrational. I think the better approach is to use FP, but look for block boundaries in the sorted array Z using comparisons that have some "give" to them -- instead of checking for strict equality of x and y, check whether abs(x-y) < EPS, where EPS is some sufficiently small number.

Comment: OK, I'm happy to take a look at your code -- do you have a link? Or you could post it as a separate answer (this is OK on SO).

Comment: ok, I will give link but not in comments :) (by rules of stackoverflow (not sure about it))
does this platform have something like chat?

Comment: There is, try going here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232769/maximum-area-rectangle-algorithm-discussion

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Ugh, typical... I think it will be fine to post a link here in the comments.

Comment: Issues so far: (1) Update `prv` to `i`, not `i - 1`; (2) use `(Z[i][3] - Z[prv][3])` instead of `(Z[prv][3] - Z[i][3])` when computing `answer` to get a positive number. I also changed `answer` to `long double` type to get more information about the answer when it's wrong, which showed that (in this example at least) the distances are correct but the displacements are wrong: They are 1 when they should be 1.4142...

Comment: It looks like your `intersection_point` is the x coord of the intersection, and you are only computing the projections of displacements along the x axis. We need the distance along L.

Comment: ok, I fixed it but it still prints wrong answer :(

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ncRKD56V prints the correct answer after fixing the things I described; not sure why yours doesn't. It still doesn't handle perfectly axis-aligned boxes, and I realised that the sort is still unreliable, since a small difference in the first or second tuple element can disturb the order.